# call function in canvas

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas

I got error `core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: this.test is not a function at klass.<anonymous>`  when try to call function in canvas

HTML

```
<canvas #canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
```

ts

```
ngOnInit() {

this.cvs.on("stagemouse:down", function(){
      console.log('Event mouse:down Triggered');
      this.test();
    })
  }

test(){
  console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: try using the arrow function definition, maybe `this` refers to the canvas and not your component in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a function with `function()`, it is not "bound", meaning the value of `this` might not always be the same depending on when and where the function is called. To declare a "bound" function, use the arrow syntax:

```js
this.cvs.on("stagemouse:down", () => {
  console.log('Event mouse:down Triggered');
  this.test();
});
```

This syntax makes `this` in the function *always* refer to the `this` that is currently there when it is created.